# How can I bring up the GRUB menu?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, password-recovery

I installed ubuntu as a dual boot system with Windows 7. I was on my user account earlier today and I changed the password. I shut down the computer and tried to re-login but I totally forgot the new password. I found a helpful tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/user-forgottenpassword.html

However, I am struggling to find the grub menu. When the computer starts up, I have two options Windows 7 or Ubuntu. I enter Ubuntu and a black screen appears for a quick second and then a purple loading screen starts. After about 20 seconds, it fades and another black screen appears with lines of code. I tried pressing down on SHIFT or pressing ESC. However, each time, it just goes to the Ubuntu login screen. What can I do to bring up the Grub menu?

Comment: struggling to find grub menu yet you say "I have two options Windows 7 or Ubuntu" That is Grub menu. can you explain better? Also it is good to say Ubuntu version (presumably 10.04)

Comment: ok. so I am using an HP computer. It loads and says Windows 7 Ubuntu. you highlight either one and press enter

Comment: it is ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 14):

HOLD "Shift" after the "power-on self test", i.e. the first few screens when your PC boots up, then you will get into Grub menu.

Comment: Sorry to sound ignorant but what do you mean by POST?

Comment: @Joe: Please don't thank literally, but vote up and accept the correct answer.

Comment: POST means "power-on self test", i.e. the first few screens when your PC boots up. You can just keep holding shift as soon as you hit the power button.

Comment: Exactly @Stefano Palazzo

Answer (score 0):

Since you sound to be new to world of Linux (at least to me) I would suggest you go for the Live CD method. Burn the CD and follow the instructions because they are easier than GRUB thing (at least to newbees). Just [download a CD from here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) and follow the [instruction here](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/user-forgottenpassword.html#live-cd)